# Port data out of docker container

Tags: docker

I use this method below to port data out of one container.

`docker run --volumes-from <data container> ubuntu tar -cO <volume path> | gzip -c > volume.tgz`

But there is one problem with it is every time it performs a backup, there will be a zombie container left. What is the good way to get that id and remove the zombie container afterward.

Thanks

Comment: Add ```--rm``` it will remove the container afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, you just want to be able to export volume data. To do that, you just need to start your initial container with a volume pointing to a directory on the host with the `-v` option. You can tar on the host without creating a container for it. Your current tactic seems a bit over-engineered ;)

Comment: Because I use Mac to dev and using docker through boot2docker, it's more convenient to do backup directly from docker container. I don't like to go in the virtual machine and copy it out and doing some sort of mount folder, it's really slow sometimes.

Comment: But the resulting tar from your current method is still on your VM, right? The only difference is that you now use a script instead of a container to create it.

Comment: yes, you are right. I have changed this complicated and experienceable method to the classic rsync.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to remove the container after executing the command, is to use the option --rm, from [here](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/reference/run/#clean-up-rm)

However, if you feel that the container you are creating will have data that you will need to 
 
1. update in real time
2. access after the container has been created

then you may also mount a [host directory as a container volume](http://docs.docker.io/en/latest/use/working_with_volumes/) and access the contents of that directory from the host.

If you start a container using the -volume option, you can also call reference the directory created on this host

> $ docker run -v /volume_directory ubuntu
>   $ container=$(docker ps -n=1 -q)
>   $ docker inspect -f '{{.Volumes}}' $container

Comment: My former comment was bad. If you use `-rm` in Docker 0.9.1 (the current version), you get: "'-rm' is deprecated, it will be replaced by '--rm' soon. See usage." Should I delete the first comment?

Comment: I think it's better that way, so yes.